# How CDI bean vs Managed bean

Tags: java, jsf, cdi, managed-bean

I have previous experience with Java SE and I've just decided to learn JSF. I'm working with JSF 2.2, Apache Netbeans 10, glassfish 5/paraya 5.184. The problem is, I've been having series of issues working with CDI beans and `ManagedBeans`

Following a tutorial online, I was able to create a login with the use of a  `WebFilter` and JSF login page based on a `SessionScoped` `ManageBean`.

However, I'm unable to access the bean property (e.g logged in username) from other JSF pages, changing the Bean to a CDI bean (`javax.inject.Named`) solved this problem (hence the properties are now accessible from other pages), but created another. Every now and then I get a `WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` error which doesn't occur present when the login controller was a `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`. Note this error is generated specifically from the `WebFilter` when `doFilter` method is called.

Also often time during the development process I get `WELD-000227: Bean identifier index inconsistency detected - the distributed container probably does not work with identical applications Expected hash: -XXXXXXXXX`. Although, I usually resolve this by removing the `implements Serializable` bit of my login bean then deploy and subsequently add it back before redeploying (this is made easy thanks to Netbean's auto deploy feature)

login.xhtml

```
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h3>User Login</h3>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3"
                columnClasses="rightalign,leftalign,leftalign">

                <h:outputText value="Username" />
                <h:inputText id="username"
                             label="Username"
                             required="true"
                             value="#{login.user}" />
                <h:message for="username"/>

                <h:outputText value="Password" />
                <h:inputSecret id="password"
                               label="Password"
                               required="true"
                               value="#{login.pwd}" />
                <h:message for="password"/>

                <h:panelGroup/>
                <h:commandButton action="#{login.validateUsernamePassword}"
                    id="login" value="Login" />                
            </h:panelGrid>            
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

Login.java

```
@ManagedBean //This error occurs if I change it to @Named  --> WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
@SessionScoped
public class Login implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1897831825228386363L;

    private String pwd;
    private String msg;
    private String user;

    public String getPwd() {
            return pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
            this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
            return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
            this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getUser() {
            return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
            this.user = user;
    }

    //validate login
    public String validateUsernamePassword() {
        boolean valid = LoginDAO.validate(user, pwd);
        if (valid) {
            HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username", user);
            try {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("explorer.xhtml");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return "explorer";
        } else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .addMessage(null,
                            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                                    "Incorrect Username and Passowrd",
                                    "Please enter correct username and Password"));
            return "login";
        }
    }

    //logout event, invalidate session
    public String logout() {
        HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
        session.invalidate();
        return "login";
    }
}
```

AuthorizationFilter.java

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {
    public AuthorizationFilter() {
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {

            HttpServletRequest reqt = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            HttpSession ses = reqt.getSession(false);

            String reqURI = reqt.getRequestURI();
            if (reqURI.indexOf("/login.xhtml") >= 0
                            || (ses != null && ses.getAttribute("username") != null)
                            || reqURI.indexOf("/public/") >= 0
                            || reqURI.contains("javax.faces.resource"))
                // this causes the WELD-001303 error
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                //Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Logger.Level.INFO, "doChain");
            else
            {
                resp.sendRedirect(reqt.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml");
            }                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

admin.xhtml

```
<!--admin.xhtml-->
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p>Welcome #{login.user}</p>
            <h:commandLink action="#{login.logout}" value="Logout"></h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

So here are my questions:

1. Why exactly does the WELD-001303 error occur at the `WebFilter` when I change the Login bean from managed to CDI?
2. Why I'm I unable to access the username property from my Login bean in other pages when the bean is managed, meanwhile it works as expected when I change the bean to CDI ?
3. Why does the login bean generate the WELD-000227 error when I modify source code that's not even inside the Login.java file ?
4. How do I correct these errors ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the full import of `SessionScoped`? note that there are two of them, and you should use the one from CDI not from ManagedBeans if you use the `javax.inject.Named`, otherwise CDI will put the bean in the default scope, which is `Dependent` and hence you will get unexpected errors like the one you see

Comment: So which ``SessionScoped`` do I use for CDI and which for ``ManagedBean`` ?

Comment: `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` with `javax.inject.Named`